# How can I refactor this if/else statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

Here's the if/else statement:

```
if number.events.blank?
  Resque.enqueue(ProcessNumbers, number.id)
elsif number.events && !number.events.ordered.first.status.downcase.include? 'delivered'
  Resque.enqueue(ProcessNumbers, number.id)
end
```

Ultimately trying to say: "If `number.events` is blank, run `enqueue`. Or if `number.events.ordered.first.status.downcase.include` includes 'delivered' (but make sure `number.events` actually has something)."

Comment: I think the `if/else` is ok as it is, but it's a little odd that both branches do exactly the same.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to combine those into one, I guess.

Comment: If you wanna combine them it's `if number.events.blank? || (number.events && !number.events.ordered.first.status.downcase.include? 'delivered')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Ruby developer, but it seems like your `number.events` check in the `elsif` is redundant since your code will only "fall through" to that `elsif` in the case that `number.events` is NOT blank. And since you have an `if...or` situation, a more concise way of putting it may be:

```
if number.events.blank? || !number.events.ordered.first.status.downcase.include? 'delivered'
    Resque.enqueue(ProcessNumbers,number.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or,

```
if !number.events.blank? && !number.events.ordered.first.status.downcase.include? 'delivered'
    Resque.enqueue(ProcessNumbers, number.id)
```

It will make sure that `number.events` actually has something.

Comment: I do not understand how you believe this code actually does the same thing? If `number.events` is blank, your code will not `enqueue` at all.